# Getting 503 while fetching topicDetails from channels list of youtube data api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, http-status-code-503

Im getting a 503 - backend error while fetching topicDetails from the channels api from the browser.

Without topicDetails it works as expected. What am I missing?

```
https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCYkM7yPFNSwpxBKnPTMhPLg&part=id%2C%20snippet%2C%20statistics%2C%20topicDetails&key=AIzaSyAa8yy0GdcGPHdtD083HiGGx_S0vMPScDM
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that Youtube support works well here. Here is the same issue reported on their issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153114055

Comment: Thanks for letting me know ! I will track it there as well.
Although the API support does recommend adding it on stack overflow -> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support

Comment: Yeah, I know it. And this is bothering. But from my experience, I never saw progress on bugs here at stack overflow, just some recommendations, and the most work happens on the issue tracker.